# BASH - how to get ride of pressing CTRL+C to move to the next command submission?

Tags: c, linux, bash, ubuntu, arduino

Very simple test in Arduino Ethernet the following code works when i do from terminal `echo 'command' | /bin/nc ip port -w 3` but same lines when i add in BASH sh files and try to execute it to submit at once many then it fails or BASH Script i have to physically press CTRL+C to try next lines.

I have to run those commands BASH scripts automatically, how can i resolve the CTRL+C issue?

Arduino:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[]=     {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xAD};
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,151);
byte gateway[]= {192,168,1,1};
byte subnet[]= {255, 255, 255,0};

int serverPort=8888;
EthernetServer server(serverPort);

int           led1 = 2;
int           led2 = 3;

void setup() {
  //Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, '8.8.8.8', gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    String clientMsg ="";
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        clientMsg+=c;
        //client.println(clientMsg);
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (clientMsg == "pin1\n") {
            client.println("You said 1:"+clientMsg);//modify the string and send it back
            clientMsg="";
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
            delay(3000);
            digitalWrite(led1, LOW);

          } else if ( clientMsg == "pin2\n" ) {
            client.println("You said 2:"+clientMsg);//modify the string and send it back
            clientMsg="";
            digitalWrite(led2, LOW);

          } else if ( clientMsg == "pin2off\n" ) {
            client.println("You said 3:"+clientMsg);//modify the string and send it back
            clientMsg="";                                  
            digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);


          }

        }

      }
    }

    delay(1);
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

I am sending now command but i have to every time press physically CTRL+C to submit and move to next

```
sun@sun-Alienware-X51:~$ cat /var/tmp/connect.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo 'pin2' | /bin/nc 192.168.1.151 8888 -w 3;
sleep 1
echo 'pin2' | /bin/nc 192.168.1.153 8888 -w 3;

sun@sun-Alienware-X51:~$ cat /var/tmp/disconnect.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "test 1"
echo "pin2off" | /bin/nc 192.168.1.151 8888 -w 2;
echo "pin2off" | /bin/nc 192.168.1.151 8888 -w 2;
echo "pin2off" | /bin/nc 192.168.1.151 8888 -w 2;

echo "test 2"
echo "pin2off" | /bin/nc 192.168.1.153 8888 -w 2;
echo "pin2off" | /bin/nc 192.168.1.153 8888 -w 2;
echo "pin2off" | /bin/nc 192.168.1.153 8888 -w 2;

sun@sun-Alienware-X51:~$ /var/tmp/connect.sh 
You said 2:pin2


^C
^Csun@sun-Alienware-X51:~$ 
sun@sun-Alienware-X51:~$ /var/tmp/disconnect.sh 
test 1
You said 3:pin2off


^CYou said 3:pin2off

^CYou said 3:pin2off

^Ctest 2
You said 3:pin2off

^CYou said 3:pin2off

^CYou said 3:pin2off

^Csun@sun-Alienware-X51:~$
```

***EDIT:*** other possible suggestions

```
echo "command" | nc ip1 -q 2 && echo "command" | nc ip2 -q 2

or

echo command >/dev/tcp/192.168.1.2/8888
```

Comment: You might be better off not opening a new connection each time.  But if you want to do that, you could try using the -q flag to netcat, which I believe gives a timeout in seconds.  What may be more complicated is handilng retry.  Consider writing your own program to parse a list of commands instead of using scripting and netcat?  Or else you may need to look at exit codes, assuming netcat sets those.

Comment: WOW - -q 2 i applied and removed -w 2 or 3. But now i see really the results are good. But when i execute from terminal straight the -q 2 is accurate 2 seconds, same terminal line when i place in connect.sh and disconnect.sh file and execute from script file. Its not 2 second, but more then 2 seconds its taking (but at-least its submitting now all the command with more then given timeout), is that normal?

Comment: and why don't you just use [`expect`](http://expect.sf.net)?